# Any recommended ultra low memory linux servers

Tags: linux, ftp

I'm looking for a ultra low memory linux server to only serve FTP requests.  CPU and disk space is not an issue.

Any good recommendations?

**EDIT**

This is for a office FTP server.  We already have a ESXi server so planning to set up the FTP as a VM.

Comment: WTF for the close?  Not even a suggestion on where to ask this question?

Comment: Damn Small Linux. Low memory requirements and resources.

Comment: @user35072 This question isn't valid here, or any other site - no sites allow shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a virtual server for $5 in the month. It's ultra low memory server but you need an internet connection.

Comment: Sorry this is for my office setup.  We already have a ESXi server so planning to set up the FTP as a VM.

Answer (score 0):

A home router flashed with DD-WRT or OpenWRT is capable of running an ftp daemon [such as ProFTPd](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/ProFTPd_Server).  Says you need the MEGA build - so you need a router model with 8MB or more of flash.  Such routers typically have 32MB of RAM.  Hope you're serious about disk space not being an issue because you literally don't have any.

A rooted Android phone with a Debian bootstrapped install might suffice.  You can also do the Debian bootstrap thing on a Palm Pre or compatible.

I'm sure someone was insane enough to write an FTP server for Windows Mobile 6.5 and below (though I've not heard of one) - most of those old phones are low memory, low speed, and out of favor meaning you should be able to get one dirt cheap.